# How to know whether we reached to end of the page or not in an android app using appium in a DYNAMIC way

Tags: selenium, scroll, appium, logcat

in appium automation, if we reach to the end of a page i want to end up my check conditions. so to know if we reached to end of the page or not i have tried some ways like

- if we reached to end element(if end element displayed we can its end
  of the page) but it is not a dynamic way
- checking previous element value with present element value. if same we can say its end of the page. But here also its not a dynamic way.

so what i'm guessing is if we take adb/appium logs/responses and compare those with before and after performing scroll action, then if same logs/response comes we can say it is end of the page right????

if above way is correct,my doubt is if we perform scroll action can we get any logs like scroll has been successfully performed & if scroll has not performed can we get logs like scroll has not been performed????

any solution is appreciated, Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solutions:

1) After each scroll action get a list of all visible elements and if it doesn't differ from your previous view you end scrolling.

2) Use scrollToEnd() from [UiScrollable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable) with

`driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("Your UiScrollable here"))`

to get to the end of the page. You can then check when you should end scrolling in your actual test.

If you don't know how to use UiScrollable there is a great article about it [here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-scroll-examples/).

Comment: As you mentioned first solution, can you say how to get all visible elements??

Comment: @Jagadeesh : do driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*") this will give u all elements

Comment: For what it's worth, if you are scrolling a list, like a menu, just save the value of the last menu item displayed, scroll, then check only the last item displayed again.  If it's the same, you've reached the end of the list - no need to check all items.